# loop through mysql subquery result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have product table that has a column named **model** and a column named **price**.

I want to write a query that updates the price for each row with a specific condition by a constant multiplier. I don't know how to loop through the sub-query and update all rows that match the criteria.
something like this:

```
UPDATE products 
for each product.name is like 'ITNC%'
begin loop    
SET price:= @newRatio * (select products.pinnumber from products where  product.name is like 'ITNC%')    
end   loop
```

Comment: SQL is a set-based language.  You don't loop each row to update.\

Comment: so isnt that possible in sql to update a row using its columns values?

Comment: Post table structure, sample input, expected output.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: XD.............

Comment: Add the update on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it with something like this.

```
UPDATE products
SET price = @newRatio * pinnumber
WHERE name LIKE 'ITNC%'
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response,
the pinnumber is different for each row in ITNC product family.
so when i use a select it brings multiple rows and throw an sql error indicating
there are multiple rows in subquery result. the pinnumber is bind to that specific row.

Comment: @sedra The pinnumber will be different for each row, depending of the value of pinnumber in that row.

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. this is the viewpoint that i lacked! it has built-in iteration hidden inside. thank you 
i was thinking that i need to do another select for collecting desired pinnumbers. i didnt know when applying a condition on UPDATE, ive already have the desired set and i can just grab the column i want and use it for updating the other column. noob!